# Tangent to parabola without derivative

Tags: euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, tangent-line

Given a parabola $y^2=2px$ we must prove that the tangent to the parabola at $P_1(x_1,y_1)$ is of the form $yy_1=p(x+x_1)$.

One way to do this is using derivatives. Another way is using Archimedes' Lemma.
A third way is the one I tried to do. I've looked up a lot for this particular proof but I wasn't able to find exactly this anywhere I've searched.

I tried to prove this using a system of equations. Tangent: $y=mx+β$, where $β=-mx_1+y_1$  and 
parabola: $y^2=2px$. Substituting the equation of the tangent in the equation of the parabola and setting $Δ=0$ for one root, after some algebra we get: $-2x_1m^2+2y_1m-p=0$

How is it possible that this is a quadratic equation if we only have one tangent line? In a similar problem with a hyperbola and a tangent we get a quadratic equation as there are two tangents, one for each part of the curve.

Which slope $m$ should I choose and why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you express the equation of the tangent at the origin in the form $y=mx+\beta$?

Comment: @amd I don't know that, how? (the final equation for the tangent still works for the origin though..)

Comment: You can’t, which is my point. Your proof is incomplete because it doesn’t cover that case.

Comment: @amd So how do I prove that this is the equation in this case as well?

Comment: You’ll either have to handle it as a special case or start with a different form of equation of a line that can express vertical lines as well.

Comment: @amd What form of equation satisfies vertical lines as well?

Comment: $ax+by+c=0$ works. It might be more convenient to put it in the *normal form* $\mathbf n\cdot(\mathbf p-\mathbf p_0)=0$. The $\mathbf n$ here is perpendicular to the line, and so normal to the parabola, which makes it easy to relate to the tangent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55983/discussion-between-michael-and-amd).

Comment: BTW, are you sure that you copied the equation of the tangent line into the problem statement correctly? What you’ve got has the right slope, but doesn't actually pass through the point $(x_1,y_1)$

Comment: @amd I think it does pass. Substituting in the equation we have $y_1^2=2px_1$ which is true since it lies on the parabola

Comment: Never mind. I misread it as $x-x_1$ instead of $x+x_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that, in the equation,
$$-2x_1m^2+2y_1m-p=0$$
The discriminant $\Delta=(2y_1)^2-4\cdot(-2x_1)\cdot (-p)=4y_1^2-8px_1$. 
And since $(x_1,y_1)$ lies on the parabola $y^2=2px$, so $y_1^2=2px_1 \implies 4y_1^2=8px_1$.

So the discriminant $\Delta=0$.

This implies only one real value of $m$.

Hence there is one and only one tangent.

Hope this helps.